# Alamofire Audio Download, Unable to play the downloaded Audio

Tags: ios, swift, download, alamofire

I am new to programming and swift, I have a problem with downloading an audio file from a server, here is the code I do:

```
var player: AVAudioPlayer?

func downloadSong()
{
    let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
    let url = "https://link for DWNL music"
    print("DESTINATION \(destination)")

    Alamofire.download(
        url,
        method: .get,
        parameters: nil,
        encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
        headers: nil,
        to: destination).downloadProgress(closure: { (progress) in
            //progress closure
        }).response(completionHandler: { (DefaultDownloadResponse) in
            let destinationUrl = DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL
            print("Downloaded file to \(DefaultDownloadResponse.destinationURL!)")

            do {
                self.player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: destinationUrl!)

                guard let player = self.player else {  return }
                player.delegate = self
                player.prepareToPlay()
                player.play()
            } catch let error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }

        })
}
```

It goes through all the code but nothing is being played... please tell me what am I doing wrong here. I have doubts with the saving of the file, i think the mistake is there. Thank you!

Comment: Hi did you get any solution?